# How to convert bytes from uint64_t to double?

Tags: c++, bit, converters

I have binary file from which I read `uint64_t` val (using little-endian). Now I want to convert this `uint64_t` to `double` (not just casting, but exactly the number that would be `double` if I entered it from the file). So the should has the same bit representation. How I should do this?

Comment: [`memcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) the `uint64_t` into a `double`

Comment: Are you converting a 64-bit integer to a double or are you converting 8-bytes into a `double`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, 64-bit integer.

Comment: Create a `double` variable.  Assign the uint64_t to the `double` variable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, they would has the same values but not the same bit representations.

Comment: @dasfex Most compilers use an IEEE standard, which comprises of a sign, mantissa and exponent.  There are 3 parts to the representation, so they will not have the same bit pattern as an integer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The point here is to reinterpret the hex value as if it were a double, not to convert the integer value to a floating-point representation of the same value.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons  There is no evidence of that.  The OP said that the conversion is between a 64-bit integer and a double.  There is no mention of hex, or octal.  In an above comment, I asked if the conversion was between an 8-byte quantity and a double.  The 8-byte quantity would be the representation in memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews From the question: *"So the should has the same bit representation."*

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I misunderstood you then. I am talk about 8-byte quantity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, edit tags. C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple portable way:

```c
uint64_t u64 = read_from_file();
double d;
memcpy(&d, &u64, sizeof(d));
```

Most compilers will generate just a couple of instructions for this.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa: what is not working? does the code fail to reinterpret the bits of the `uint64_t` as a `double` or does the compiler generate a call to `memcpy()`? What CPU? what compiler? what options?

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to do it:

```cpp
uint64_t val = someCodeThatReadsTheValue();
auto valPtr = &val;
double dVal = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(valPtr);
```

As pointed out in the comments, this is **Undefined Behaviour**, although it will work in most compilers.

If you don't want to trust your compiler you can do the following.

```cpp
uint64_t val1 = someCodeThatReadsTheValue();
double val2;
char* p1 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val1);
char* p2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val2);
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(uint64_t); i++)
    p2[i] = p1[i];
```

Droping this just as a fun fact, it's easier to just use `memcpy` as in @chqrlie's answer. Unless you can't use the C standard library.

Comment: Is Undefined Behaviour

Comment: This solution invokes undefined behavior as you are accessing the data through an incompatible type.

Comment: Helpful reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing

Comment: Also this: https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The union solution is valid for C, but type-punning through unions is undefined behavior for C++.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianGibbons - that was something that I read though the cppreference.com information and didn't find, and didn't follow up with the standard. Noted.